# Change the used PHP version

Tags: drush

I have  PHP 5.6 and 7.1 on my system. I want to use PHP 5.6 for the Drupal 7 projects, and PHP 7.1 for the Drupal 8 projects.

I am having problems getting this setup.
In the [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1302418) I found that I should set an alias like this in my ~/.zshrc.

```
 alias drush='DRUSH_PHP=/usr/bin/php56 /usr/bin/drush'
```

The problem is that when I start a new terminal and run `drush ev 'print PHP_VERSION'`, it still prints out 7.1.6.

I tried to alias PHP to /usr/bin/php56 but that also did not work.

I also tried the following suggestions (and many others), but they didn't work.

- [Drush in a system with 2 PHP-Versions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/186694/drush-in-a-system-with-2-php-versions)
- [Drush–alias to run it with another php version](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/220297/drush-alias-to-run-it-with-another-php-version)

I think this changed in more recent Drush versions, like version 8.1.12 I am using.

Can anyone help me find the correct way to do this in more modern Drush versions?

Comment: I managed to put the correct php default in cli by putting it first in my path. I get the correct response now when I do php -v but drush stopped giving any output.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try in your .profile:

```
export DRUSH_PHP='usr/bin/php56'
```

I think you are mixing up alias with setting an environment variable.